# SolR PreserverMulti only for specific field

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using **SolR** for searching documents provided with numbers of metadata.
(in average, more than 2 Mb per document)
I'm focused on optimizing data amount to transfer, due to performance issue.

On query parameters, I'm using

1. `fl`: to specifiy a few fields that I always need
2. `hl.fl` for also this main fields, but also for additional fields on which I want data only if they contain requested text.

To preserve integrity and merge highlighted data with returned documents, I use `hl.preserveMulti`. (the only way I've found to merge which highlighted value to linked to raw original value)

- That works perfectly for main fields (1)
- But in my second (2) case, it returns too many useless data

I'm wondering if I can specify `hl.preserveMulti=true` only for main fields, and set it to `false` on extra fields.

I have not found anything in [documentation about highlighting](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_1/highlighting.html) on this.

Any tips / advice ?

Comment: The common syntax for field specific arguments is `f.fieldname.<argument>`, so `f.fieldname.hl.preserveMulti=true` (or false) if the argument is supported as a field specific argument - I'd try to start there, at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set field specific parameters by using the `f.<fieldname>.<argument>` syntax, so to set a specific `hl` parameter for just `fieldname`, use:

```
f.fieldname.hl.preserveMulti=true
```